# rollup custom cli arguments for the config throwing errors

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I have an app in progress which requires 3 micro code bases and some iframe postMessage stuff.

Controlling the build of all these i aim to manage from a single rollup config file and injecting arguments in via cli:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev:child": "rollup -c rollup.config.js -w --for_type child",
    "dev:parent": "rollup -c rollup.config.js -w --for_type parent",
    "dev:sidebar": "rollup -c rollup.config.js -w --for_type sidebar",
```

My rollup config works but the issue is that rollup complains that `for_type` is a non recognised argument.

What is the proper way of injecting custom arguments to rollup?

I cannot see anything here: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files

Answer (score 3):

When you export a function instead of an object in `rollup.config.js`, the first argument of the function will be a CLI arguments object. For example, if you config is:

```js
export default cliArgs => {
    let build = {
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: [/* ... */],/
        plugins: [/* ... */]
    };

    switch (cliArgs.for_type) {
        case 'child':
            // Customise build for child
            break;
        case 'parent':
            // Customise build for parent
            break;
        case 'sidebar':
            // Customise build for sidebar
            break;
        default:
            // No CLI argument
            break;
    }

    return build
};
```

Have another look at the [documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

From https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files

> You can even define your own command line options if you prefix them with config:

```
export default commandLineArgs => {
  if (commandLineArgs.configDebug === true) {
    return debugConfig;
  }
  return defaultConfig;
};
```

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from this answer (it wasn't for me), in OP's case they would need to change the argument name to `--config_for_type`.

Comment: Downvoted because I'm sick of people posting answers and tutorials that make major assumptions and completely omit key bits of foundational knowledge that someone who is still learning WOULD NOT be aware of. The internet is rife with this crap approach. If you're already taking the time to help, which is awesome, please, do it thoroughly and include all the steps - put yourself in the shoes of the learner, thoroughly. There's no point doing anything unless you do it PROPERLY. Thanks BlueGreenMagick!