# Add custom variable to rollup config

Tags: javascript, node-modules, package.json, rollup

I am trying to do custom build for individual element using rollup config. For complete build I have added script in package.json:

```
"build": "npm run rollup -c "
```

Which can be run through `npm run build` 
Now I want to have build for each element for which I have already added changes in rollup config. In order to get that script work I need to pass component name from build script.

```
npm run build --componentName
```

I am not getting idea of how I can fetch that `componentName` in my rollup config.
I have followed this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170728/rollup-custom-cli-arguments-for-the-config-throwing-errors) but unfortunately this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass arguments to the underlying npm executable use : `npm run build -- --componentName`.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-run-script